# Python: Choleski decomposition of matrix read from file with blank lines

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I have a `txt` file which represents the entries of a matrix. It is structured like this:

```
columns  rows              value

x1       x1                matrix value for x1-x1
x1       x2                matrix value for x1-x2
x1       x3                matrix value for x1-x3
.
. 
.
x1      x_n               matrix value for x1 - x_n
(blank line)
x2       x1               matrix value for x2 - x1
x2       x2               matrix value for x2 - x2 
x2       x3               matrix value for x2 - x3
.
.
.
x2        x_n             matrix value for x2 - x_n
(blank line)
.
.
.
```

and so on...

I need to read it and store the matrix values in a matrix, to be plotted with `imshow` and also put in a way such that I can act on it with the Cholesky decomposition implemented in `numpy`.

There are two problems I am facing :

1) skipping the blank lines in the file (if that matters, I know at which line they occur)
I tried to solve this by isolating the third column from my original file and using the following on it

```
with open('thirdcolumn.txt') as f_in: 
    lines = list(line for line in (l.strip() for l in f_in) if line)
```

2) nevertheless, if I do that and reshape the matrix

```
matrix = np.reshape(lines,(n,n))
```

this is not good for the Cholesky decomposition:

```
No loop matching the specified signature and casting
was found for ufunc cholesky_lo
```

nor for plotting

```
TypeError: Image data can not convert to float
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere in the code your provided (although it's not much) where you convert the `string` values from your text file into numbers of some sort.  Are your values still strings?  That `TypeError` implies they are.

Comment: @DanielF that's a problem indeed. I still have strings while I should have numbers. How do I do that?

Comment: `matrix.astype(float)`, although I think `matplotlib` already tried and that and failed, which means you probably have a badly formatted string somewhere.

Comment: indeed I tried and I get the same error...but I can't spot the badly formatted string anywhere